# How to modifying a bound ObservableCollection from a UserControl, if the DataContext comes from the hosting window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, observablecollection

Using WPF, MVVM. I have a control, ModifyZooControl, which is a UserControl. This is a control because I want to add it to multiple windows.

One of the windows is ModifyZooWindow, which gets the DataContext from MVVMLight.
I add the user control in the window's xaml:

```
<uc:ModifyZooControl/>
```

The ModifyZooControl has this, for listing the Zoo instance's  `ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals` property:

```
    <ListBox Name="Animals" ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

This works so far, I have the Window, and inside of it the ModifyZooControl listing the animals.

Next, I want to modify the list of the animals from the control's codebehind. How do I do that?

`Animals.Items.Add(newAnimal)` doesn't work, because of "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead".

How do I reach the original viewmodel Animals observablecollection from the UserControl's codebehind?

As I understand one choice is to add two properties for the ObservableCollections to the UserControl. And set their values when instantiating the UserControl from the Window. Then I would have references to the original ObservableCollections, and could modify them. 
But is that really needed, considering that there is already some kind of reference to the collections through the Window's datacontext...?

Also, is a UserControl the right choice for this kind of thing? Should I use a frame rather, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I reach the original viewmodel Animals observablecollection from the UserControl's codebehind?

You typically would not do this.  In general, it's typically a better approach to bind the "command" that's requiring this as a command, so the logic can remain in the ViewModel.  The ViewModel should be the one adding the new `Animal` instance to it's own collection.

If you must do this for some reason, you could cast the data context:

```
// In code behind:
Zoo vm = this.DataContext as Zoo;
if (vm != null)
{
    ObservableCollection<Animal> items = vm.Animals;
    items.Add(newAnimal);
}
```